# Cómo ejecutar correctamente un proyecto de Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo el siguiente mensaje al ejecutar un proyecto de Xamarin, ya lo probé en dos máquinas y me sale el mismo error. Instalé Xamarin desde el mismo Visual Studio Installer, se debe a eso o qué podría hacer para solucionarlo, ya que no responde cuando trato de ejecutarlo y se cuelga durante mucho tiempo. Gracias por su ayuda.

**Extension 'Xamarin  Templates 1.0.56' likely caused 9 seconds of unresponsiveness...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparecen estos warnings:

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from
>   2.5.1.444934 to 2.5.0.280555. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.   SmartReport.Android ->
>   SmartReport -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.1.444934)   SmartReport.Android
>   -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.0.280555)

otro:

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from
>   2.5.1.444934 to 2.5.0.280555. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.   SmartReport.iOS ->
>   SmartReport -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.1.444934)   SmartReport.iOS ->
>   Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.5.0.280555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los warnings son porque tienes diferentes versiones del paquete Xamarin.Forms en el core y en iOS, revisa y actualiza los paquetes de nuget de toda la solución, para que este todo igualado.

Lo del unresponsive... pf... a mi me daba por ejemplo por culpa del antivirus, que me escaneaba cosas de mis proyectos mientras los usaba. Si no tienes ssd y tienes "poca" ram puede ser hasta normal. Intenta tener todo actualizado, visual studio, extensiones y paquetes.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, también pensé en solucionarlo actualizando los NuGets y sí solucionó el mensaje, pero solo actualiza Xamarin.Forms hay otros paquetes que no los actualiza y sale este error **Severity Code Description Project Path File Line Suppression State Error  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'SmartReport.Android'.** Qué debería hacer?

Comment: Hay ciertos paquetes que no debes actualizar nunca, que son todos los que empiezan por Xamarin.Android eso es porque Xamarin tiene versiones de las librerias de Android más actualizadas que las que sabe usar Xamarin.Forms. Solo tienes que actualizar forms y el ya actualiza las que necesita de ese tipo. Luego hay librerias que depende del proyecto no puedes usar la última versión (en mi caso Autofac, por ejemplo) o que dependen de otras librerias.

Comment: Genial gracias @Mulflar